# Extract the "value= " from my response code using the following xpath query

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I have the following response :

```
input id=\"order_id\" name=\"order[id]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"42307\"  "
```

And I want to get in Jmeter the value of :

```
value=\"42307\"
```

And I am using the xpath extractor query :

```
//input[@id='order_id']/value
```

But it fails to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct regexp. it's just 'value=(.+?)', the only left problem is that it returns \"42307\" and I need just 42307 .

Answer (score 0):

First I think you mean regex. Xpath doesn't make any sense unless you're talking about searching an XML document.

The regex to get the value of the `value` field would be this assuming it will always be an integer:

```
value=[\\"]?(\d+)[\\"]?
```

If it can be any ASCII character, then you would replace the `\d` with a `.` (period):

```
value=[\\"]?(.+)[\\"]?
```